# How do I tell my application to close?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have just discovered the nifty unhandled exception handler for cocoa-touch.

Now that I can gracefully notify the user about any unhandled exceptions that might crash my application, I'd like to shut down my application after notifying the user that a crash has occured.

Does anyone know how to shut down an application programmatically?

Comment: Can you post a link for the unhandled exception handler? I haven't seen that yet.

Comment: http://www.restoroot.com/Blog/2008/10/18/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminate]; - that won't build the screenshot Springboard uses to animate the application's exit, though, so the screen will just go black until the icons move in. There doesn't seem to be a published way to do this; the UIApplication header doesn't even mention the -terminate method, so you may just not be meant to do it at all.

Comment: I think you mean [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate], rather than UIApplication.

Comment: No. Note tags: "iphone" and "cocoa-touch".

Comment: *** -[UIApplication terminate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1214900

... using `exit(0);` works perfectly, though.

Comment: My app was just rejected because of `exit(0);`. It looks like a crash. I use to inform the user when there is no internet connection and once he closes the alert I close the app by using `exit(0);`. Appears that Apple doesn't like it...

Answer (score 2):

```
exit(0);
```

will do the trick...

Comment: My app was just rejected because of `exit(0);`. It looks like a crash. I use to inform the user when there is no internet connection and once he closes the alert I close the app by using `exit(0);`. Appears that Apple doesn't like it...

Comment: Yes. If you are at all interested in submitting your app to the app store, **don't do this**.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation says there is no "normal" way to shut down. In your case - an unhandled exception - immediate termination makes sense anyway.